# folding.vim file, for a specific filetype, is being ignored

Tags: folding, filetype

I want to write a custom fold-method file for `.paul` files (based on the example at [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/49.html)). However, it appears that my `folding.vim` file is being ignored.

I'm running VIM version 8.2.1972 (on mac os 11.2.3)

- `~/.vimrc` contains nothing but
  `syntax on`
- `~/.vim/filetype.vim`  contains

```
" my filetype file
        if exists("did_load_filetypes")
          finish
        endif
        augroup filetypedetect
          au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.txt         setfiletype txt
          au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.paul        setfiletype paul
        augroup END
```

- `~/.vim/ftplugin/paul/folding.vim` contains
  `set foldmethod=expr`

If I do `vim sadf.paul` then `:set ft?` returns  `filetype=paul` so the filetype detection is working.

However, `:set foldmethod?`  returns `foldmethod=manual`, whereas I had expected to see `foldmethod=expr`.

As a test, I then changed folding.vim to contain
`set foldmethod=bogus`
to see if I would get an error when the file was processed.

However, I see no error from the `=bogus` statement in `.vim/ftplugin/paul/folding.vim`, which makes me think that the file is never being sourced/run. And, per the suggestion from Christian Brabandt, running `:scriptnames` confirms that `~/.vim/ftplugin/paul/folding.vim` was not sourced.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: check with `:scriptnames` if your file is actually being sourced

Comment: 1. You should not create `filetype.vim`. Use ftdetect instead. 2. Must have at least `filetype plugin on`.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You should *not* post answers in the question—instead, post them in an answer which can be separately voted on/accepted. Consider taking the [tour] and checking out [ask] and [answer]. I’ve [edit]ed your question for clarity and removed the answer; you can find it if you wish to post it as an answer in the history. (Our long-time members should know to avoid answering in the comments, which are for clarification.)

Comment: Also, you should consider using `setlocal` for filetype plugins.

Comment: Check output of the `:filetype` command, I bet you have `plugin:OFF` and that's what's causing the problem. You can fix that by adding `filetype plugin indent on` to your vimrc file. Or you can delete your vimrc file, which will make Vim load the `defaults.vim` file which enables that setting. (See `:help defaults.vim` for more details. You can also explicitly load `defaults.vim` from your vimrc, if you want more customizations.) Let me know if that solves the problem, in that case I'll post it as an answer. Cheers!

Comment: Hi https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/18609/filbranden,   That was the issue. Thanks!  Note however that Matt's earlier comment give the same answer (in less detail).  I have created an answer incorporating his comment.   I don't know enough about stackexchange to know if it makes sense for you to also submit a (more detailed) answer.   Paul

Answer (score 0):

This answer is from Matt. Copied here from his comment.

1. You should not create filetype.vim. Use ftdetect instead.
2. Must have at least filetype plugin on

Comment: This was the answer I needed, specifically #2.  I added `filetype plugin on` in my .vimrc and now I see the correct response from `:set foldmethod?`. Also, `:scriptnames` now shows that ~/.vim/ftplugin/paul/folding.vim has been sourced.
Per Matt's advice (in #1) I also got rid of .vim/filetime.vim and instead created .vim/ftdetect/paul.vim
Thanks, everyone, for the prompt and helpful responses!